# Run chi-squared test on a data.frame

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, chi-squared

I have this data.frame:

```
df <- data.frame(xy = c("x", "y"), V1  = c(3, 0), V2 = c(0, 0), V3 = c(5, 0), V4 = c(5, 2))
df 
  xy V1 V2 V3 V4
1  x  3  0  5  5
2  y  0  0  0  2
```

I want to know if `x` or `y` is more associated with any of `V1`, `V2`, `V3` or `V4`. To test this, I can use a chi-squared.

This is what I've tried, none of which work:

```
chisq.test(df)
chisq.test(as.matrix(df))
chisq.test(as.table(df))
```

How can I run a chi-squared test on `df`?

Comment: TrY `chisq.test(as.matrix(df[,-1]))`

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your data structure. How many observations of `x` and `y` are there? For `x` is it 1, 5, 13 or >13?
For `y`, is it 1, 2 or >2?
If >, don't you/we need to know how many?

Comment: 13 observations of x and 2 of y

Comment: check my answer on similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44290288/4683950)

Answer (score 1):

Both of following work (you need to remove first column):

```
chisq.test(df[,-1])
chisq.test(as.matrix(df[,-1]))

> chisq.test(df[,-1])

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  df[, -1] 
X-squared = NaN, df = 3, p-value = NA

Warning message:
In chisq.test(df[, -1]) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> chisq.test(as.matrix(df[,-1]))

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  as.matrix(df[, -1]) 
X-squared = NaN, df = 3, p-value = NA

Warning message:
In chisq.test(as.matrix(df[, -1])) :
  Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
>
```

Answer (score -1):

use this:

```
df <- as.table(rbind(c(3,0,5,5),c(0,0,0,2)))
> df
  A B C D
A 3 0 5 5
B 0 0 0 2
> chisq.test(df)

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  df
X-squared = NaN, df = 3, p-value = NA

Warning message:
In chisq.test(df) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

the result got warning maybe because of your data containing zero.

Comment: Pleas comment houd answer Some more. Exploit what THE poster code thus and Clarice tour remraketten Aboutaleb "warning"