# How to loop chi sq test in R

Tags: r, loops, chi-squared

I have the table with alternative and reference allele counts. How could I loop chi sq test in R to run it for each row?  I attached the picture of my table. I need to perform chi sq test with altCount and refCount columns.

```
   altCount refCount
     8        6
     3        7
     4        9
```

I need the p-value for each row. I am very new to R. I figured out how to perform chi sq test on individual rows but since I have several thousands rows I need to make a loop to run it all at once.
I did:

```
bcz <- read.delim("C:/cygwin64/home/sbomb/tables/bc_z_alleles.csv")
a = bcz[1,6]
b = bcz[1,7]
c = c(a,b)
d = c(0.5,0.5)
chisq.test(
     x = c,
     p = d, 
 )
```

but I do not know how to loop it for whole table. Could you please explain me how to do it with all details?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMRGR.png)

Comment: Posting pictures of data isn't very helpful. Try to include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in the question itself which gives sample input and clearly shows the desired output.

Comment: as mr. Flick explained, you need to show data. saying this, I think this example may give you lead to try and then post if you cannot solve yourself. This time with reproducible example. Good luck http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25350618/run-chi-squared-test-on-a-data-frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest loop for a beginner still is the for loop:

```
d <- data.frame(a = c(8,3,4), b = c(6,7,9))
for(row in 1:nrow(d)){
    print(row)
    print(chisq.test(c(d[row,1],d[row,2])))
}
```

The same can be done with

```
apply(d, 1, chisq.test)
```

The latter is shorter and gives you a list as your result, which is probalby better for further evaluation.

Comment: Thank you for your advise but what should I do if in my data table the number of rows are 44,850, so I cannot just retype each value like a = c(8,3,4)?

Comment: I think I found the answer. If I type:    d <- data.frame(a = test1[,1], b = test1[,2])  it works correctly.